# How do start Tomcat in a Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, tomcat

I just installed Docker and am learning to use it.

I installed the Oracle Linux 9 Slim image and started it using `docker run --name myContainer ...`. Next I went into the container using `docker exec -it myContainer bash` and downloaded and configured Tomcat 9. Took a few tries as I had to add port mapping to the run. Now, everything is set up.

When I reboot the host machine (actually VM), the containers are understandibly no longer running and need to be started with `docker start myContainer` command. This starts the container itself but not the TC service within in. How do I set the container to run the startup.sh script when it starts?

Comment: You're supposed to install tomcat at the Dockerfile step, without having the container created yet. docker exec should be reserved for debugging, it's not intended for a normal use of a container in Docker. Else use for example LXC which is intended to run a *system* in a container, not an *application*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe will be simpler to use docker container from hub. [Here](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat) is link to this container.

The command you need is:

```
docker pull tomcat
```

Comment: Perhaps. I used a Oracle Linux image as base as I need to install a number of other components that my application uses. I haven't gotten to that step yet. Shall do once I get this sorted.

Comment: @HussainAkbar, IMHO you want to set container with big, monolithic image. Which is not the philosophy of containers.